# How do I get Gespeaker to launch, I keep getting an error that says something about dbus.?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, lubuntu, dbus

I've already tried reinstalling the program, I even tried installing the .deb file from Gespeaker's website. If it helps I'm running Lubuntu 17.04 (I couldn't seem to find an ask Lubuntu sorta thing so I came here).
I tried running Gespeaker in the terminal here is what I got.

```
loading available plugins...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gespeaker.py", line 46, in <module>
    imp.load_module(name, file, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/share/gespeaker/plugins/plugin_dbus/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import dbus
ImportError: No module named dbus
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to fix a similar issue from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340333).

I installed dbus via:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dbus
```